# Baking just colors with bake type on diffuse is extremely slow, used to be much faster but I'm not sure what the problem is now

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, texturing, uv, baking

Every time I try to bake, it takes a really long time for the progress bar to go up, it used to be faster a couple days ago but today it suddenly became slow. My PC is certainly fast enough, 1660 TI, 32 GB RAM, Ryzen 7 3700X. I don't know what the problem is but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Baking is a rendering function, so in Cycles it's affected by the number of rendering samples.

If you're baking a property which is not affected by lights (i.e. base color, without diffuse light, indirect light) you can turn down the samples even to 1, to speed up the process.

Where lights and shadows matter (like Ambient Occlusion) you will need more samples for better results.